# Is minimum of two convex functions also convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

We are provided with two convex functions f(x) and g(x) and we are supposed to comment on the convexity of min{f(x),g(x)}.

I start out by writing the equations implied when we convexity of f(x) and g(x) are stated,

i.e  f[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λf(x) + (1-λ)f(y)....(i)

and, g[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λg(x) + (1-λ)g(y)....(ii)

Now let us assume another function, say h(x)= min{f(x),g(x)}

Since h(x)= min{f(x),g(x)}
h(x) <= f(x) and h(x) <= g(x)

Now since h(x) <= f(x)

Cannot we write equation (i) as h[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λf(x) + (1-λ)f(y)

Similarly, equation (ii) as h[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λg(x) + (1-λ)g(y)

and with these two new equations we are able to conclude that

h[λx + (1-λ)y] <= min[λf(x) + (1-λ)f(y),λg(x) + (1-λ)g(y)]

=> h[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λmin[f(x),g(x)] + (1-λ)min[f(y),f(y)]

=> h[λx + (1-λ)y] <= λh(x) + (1-λ)h(y)

Which proves h(x) which is min{f(x),g(x)} is a convex function but searching many websites including math.stackexchange I got to know that h(x) is not necessarily convex so where have I gone wrong? Please help!

Comment: In the last part you tried to use something along the lines of $min(a+b,c+d)\leq min(a,c)+min(b,d)$ which is not true.

Comment: Draw a picture of two parabolas.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3338819/42969

Comment: Take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$. Clearly they are both convex. $h(x) = min(f(x),g(x)) = -|x|$. $h(x)$ is not convex. Actually, its quite the opposite, since it is concave.

Comment: I think this is true about *maximum* of a set of real convex functions, rather than minimum, so long as the functions have the same domain. This is due to the fact that the intersection of convex subsets of R^2 is convex. Or something like that.